# How do i test/validate that an XSD schema is valid?

Tags: xsd, schema

How do i test/validate that an XSD schema is valid ? I am not looking for how to validate an XML file against an XSD but how to ensure that the XSD schema is valid and correct before using it to develop and test against it.

Answer (score 0):

Most xml schema definition editors have this option. Payed products like Altova Xml Spy or Liquid Studio can be used for this. Eclipse has a xsd editor option and Visual Studio can do this for you. Maybe even notepad++ has a plugin for this. The options are there, it all depends on what you prefer to use.